# How to change font by providing path?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

How can I change the vscode font by providing a path to the respective `.ttf` file I want to use? Simply providing the name in `settings.json` somehow doesn't work (maybe the expected name is different from the file name of the font).

Comment: install the font in your OS and use its name

Comment: @rioV8 I just said in my question that this doesn't work...

Comment: after installing the font you don't specify the path

Comment: @rioV8 but my question is whether there is a possibility to specify the path (maybe I installed my font somewhere, where vscode doesn't find it or whatever).

Comment: can you do it in Google Chrome with a file path? AFAIK Not, so also not in VSC